# Turning a button into a jQuery UI icon?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, css, jquery-ui

How would I turn this button:

```
<%= button_to "+1", video_votes_path( :video_id => video.id, :type => "up" ), :remote => true %>
```

into an icon provided by jQuery UI?

I tried adding the class to it:

```
<%= button_to "+1", video_votes_path( :video_id => video.id, :type => "up" ), :class => 'ui-icon-triangle-1-n', :remote => true %>
```

but this creates a weird looking button that still has '+1' inside of it.

I put this code in my application.js file:

```
$('input:submit, input:reset').each(function(){
      $(this).replaceWith('<button type="' + $(this).attr('type') + '">' + $(this).val() + '</button>');
     });

    $('button:submit').button({
      icons: {
       secondary: 'ui-icon-triangle-1-n'
      } 
    });
```

Comment: icon with a URL? or just an icon?

Comment: just an icon from the jQuery UI

Comment: I assume you also want to convert any triggers on the button to the image? Don't know RoR but, why not just look at the HTML that is generated and grab that with JQ?

Comment: By adding the class to the RoR code, I get this html: `<input class="ui-icon-triangle-1-n" type="submit" value="+1">` but it doesn't work correctly

Answer (score 0):

`button_to` actually generates an input element inside a form. jQuery UI only supports inputs of type submit and reset, so see if the generated markup falls under that category.

As for an actual solution, you could try converting the inputs into button tags. Take a look at [this](http://www.robertmullaney.com/2010/11/29/style-submit-and-reset-buttons-with-icons-using-jquery-ui/).

Comment: I tried this, and the converting code works, but I can't get the icon to appear... Instead a random button from the jQuery styling appears. Why is this? I double checked to make sure I include everything...

Comment: Did you include the part of the code that assigns the icons to the `submit` and `reset` buttons?

Comment: yea, look at the question details to see what I've put in my application.js file/

Comment: Did you wrap those statements within `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`?

Comment: yep I did. The button styling changes, but I can't seem to get the icon I want...

Comment: I feel like maybe I want a link instead? I just want voting up/down buttons with arrows that change color when you click on them.

Comment: That sounds reasonable! In fact, it's how Stack Overflow seems to implement the vote up and down buttons.

Comment: yeah, except that I need to be able to transfer the functionality of the button to the link. Do you know how to do this in RoR? My button code is in the answer details.

Comment: Give this a try: `link_to '+1', video_votes_path(:video_id => video.id, :type => 'up'), :remote => true, :class => 'ui-icon-triangle-1-n'`.

Comment: the link works (although I had to add `:method => :post` to it) but the icon is not appearing :/